# .htaccess detecting desktop or mobile and auto redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

-Hey Guys,

i have a big problem with our website (build in Adobe Muse). My webseite is:
www.xyz.de (desktop version) and www.xyz.de/phone (mobile version)

when i type www.xyz.de/phone on my desktop it open the mobil version, when i type www.xyz.de on my phone it autoredirect to /phone version, which is right.

So is there any options to detect a browser or a dekstop and redirect after that?

What i need:
Detect where the customer comes from and redirect to the right version.

Now i have theese htacces codes:

```
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#404-Error
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /404-error.html



ErrorDocument 400 /404-error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /404-error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404-error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404-error.html

CheckSpelling Off
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule> 

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 3600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

Kind regards, and thanks in advance.